# How to create Hangfire email Scheduler using Oracle database in .NET Core web API 6?

Tags: c#, oracle, asp.net-core-webapi, hangfire

What I am supposed to do is create a stand alone email scheduler that will take see any outstanding assignments in the Oracle database and email the recipients daily of said assignments in .NET Core. Although there is a somewhat complete tutorial on creating a webservice that will do this job, I was recommended to try out hangfire which seems to be the easier option and that webservice is an old solution. There is are a couple of problems:

1. Most of the tutorials on YouTube are using ssms integration but I am using Oracle
2. The most recent tutorials are using .NET Core web API 5 but I am using 6, and am unfamiliar with how to modify to my current version.
3. I do not know how to implement the controller code

I understand the basics, and I will show you what I know so far:

1. I know that the connection string must be in the appsettings.json which I have done and installed the nuget package Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core
2. The hangfire server and dbcontext must be configured in the Program.cs but I do not know how

   using Hangfire;

   var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

   // Add services to the container.

   builder.Services.AddHangfire(x=>x.UseSqlServerStorage(string.Format(@"")));
   builder.Services.AddHangfireServer();

   builder.Services.AddControllers();
   // Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
   builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
   builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

   var app = builder.Build();

   // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
   if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
   {
   app.UseSwagger();
   app.UseSwaggerUI();
   }

   app.UseHangfireDashboard("/mydashboard");

   app.UseHttpsRedirection();

   app.UseAuthorization();

   app.MapControllers();

   app.Run();

I tried to follow from a YouTube tutorial which is this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HF2VWcxcKy8. He did this in Startup.cs but web API 6 only has Program.cs, also he is using sqlserverstorage but I need to use Oracle database. There is also the question of this which he used for ssms, and I am wondering if I have to do it for Oracle because after searching I don't see anyone using this way:

[image]

Next I created the model:

```
namespace EmailTaskScheduler.Models
{
    public class MailObj
    {
        public string Email { get; set; }  
        public string Scheme_Name { get; set; }
        public string Ptt_ID { get; set; }
        public string Exc_Abb { get; set; }

    }
}
```

The main problem now is the controller, I don't know how implement it.

```
using EmailTaskScheduler.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace EmailTaskScheduler.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class HangfireController : ControllerBase
    {
        MailObj _omailObj = new MailObj();
    }
}
```

I know that I have to:

1. Write an Oracle command to find the outstanding task and user emails and corresponding
2. Send the emails about the task to the recipients scheduled daily

I do not know how to write the code for that. If there is someone who can give an example or explanation it would be greatly appreciated, because I am stumped.

Comment: The screenshots you posted aren't exactly relevant. `UseSqlServerStorage` configures SQL Server storage. If you want to use Oracle you'll have to use a NuGet package that provides Oracle storage, like [Hangfire.Oracle.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Hangfire.Oracle.Core). The .NET *Framework* OLEDB connection wizard has no effect on a .NET Core project

Comment: In any case, post code as *text*, not images. Images can't be copied, googled, compiled or tested. Don't ask people to type your code just to reproduce your problem

Comment: alright thanks for input, i will change edit it to text, and what is hangfire.oracle.core?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos : In this case the Op has the Model and can use the Code First approach to create the database.  See : https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/entity-framework-core.aspx?force_isolation=true

Comment: @jdweng, although I have created a model, the data I need is in the oracle database, and I want to use an oracle command to call it

Comment: The command are the same an independent of database (except  for syntax of query).  You have a connection string and instead of using the library SQLClient you use the Oracle Library.  Every thing else is the same.  The Net/Core library created similar commands for each type database to make the transition between different databases easy.

Comment: @jdweng can you how to configure it and for the controller as well?

Comment: if you have only one task which sends emails whenever there is an entry in database then using hangfire would be an overkill. in my opinion you can simply use IHostedService or background service which runs continuously and checks database for new entry and sends email. you can look at this [article](https://medium.com/@niteshsinghal85/running-automatic-task-in-asp-net-core-webapi-d5605b3a1114) which gives example on how background service can be used.

Comment: If you are using Entity you would create the Oracles tables/fields using Code First Approach (c# class models).  See : https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/odpnt/entityCodeFirst.html#GUID-F8587AB2-DFD8-4B05-9520-52B32C9E143B

Comment: @CodingMytra, the hangfire is already very new to me, and I am having trouble with it, the IHostedService you just introduced is also very new to me, I have been researching on hangfire and oracle and webapi from the past two days (with poor results). I am not sure whether I would want to switch to something completely different now

Comment: @CodingNeeded, I understand but it will save your time in long run as maintaining code will be easy with less external dependency. if you are still in analysis phase then you can give it try.

Comment: @CodingMytra, I saw the link you gave and the example was very basic. My programming skill is still not up to par and I mostly require research on youtube and google on how to code it. Could you share or is there an example on how to send emails everyday at a certain time from oracle database using IHostedService?

Comment: basically you want complete solution then what would you do ? Stackoverflow can provide you guidance not a place where get complete code and you just simply copy. you have to put some effort here. basically you have three different task. 1. sending emails(you need to search) 2. Automatically at certain time(article covers this) 3. Reading data from oracle database( you need to explore this). and you have to wire all three code together to get the result.

Comment: Yes I was, sorry about that cause I was getting tired of looking at different code. Since the article you sent covers the automatic sending, then I will further research about it. But I am genuinely having trouble with the third task, connecting and reading data from oracle database. All the tutorials are showing connection with ssms and any question about oracle just tells me to download the nuget packages which I have done. also the IHostedService uses .net core web api 6? because in the microsoft documentation mentions of a worker service template